# Python 3.5.1 regex doesn't match as expected

Tags: python, regex

I tested my regex with *Regex101* already, but when I tried in *Python 3.5.1* it returns `None`

Here's my [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fC0lI5/4)

And here's my Python code. Not sure if I miss anything.

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)-([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)', re.MULTILINE)
>>> m = p.match('NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 7AM-7:30AM EXCEPT SUNDAY')
>>> print(m)
None
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `match` will search from the start of the string. Use `search` instead.